# Event when user shares a page (Facebook SDK)

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, dom-events, facebook-like

Is there an event that fires when a user shares something on their wall?

I'm successfully capturing the subscribe event when they click "Like", but I want one when they share it in the drop down box that shows up when you click the Like button.

I can't find any documentation on this, so I'm wondering if this exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you need to listen for the comment.create (instead of the edge.create) event in the FB callback...

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

I haven't tried it, but I suspect it works.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working. It fires just fine when you post a comment on the page using the Facebook comments feature, but not when a page is shared via the Like button.

Comment: I've found the FB callback API to be less than 100% reliable... if you're sure you're using it as documented, I'd file a bug with them.